# Using Touchpad gestures in wxPython?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am trying to create an app using wxPython that has a side swipe gesture in it i.e. on the Mac touchpad. I had a search around and I can't find any reference to multitouch support in wx. Does anybody know if there is a class that will allow me to get this input? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-touch really isn't supported. If the touch can be translated to just normal mouse events, then wx can support that. So theoretically wx should support a swipe but you'll have to do it yourself by watching EVT_MOTION and checking which direction the mouse movement is going in.

See also the following links:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wxpython-users/E4SMMUPwgNI
- http://pymt.eu/